# Vim mapping two NERDTree command as a single key stoke

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Using VIM with NERDTree and NERDTreeTab, have following key map in my .vimrc so I can find it just by pressing F5

```
map <F5> :NERDTree<cr>
```

The problem is that I want cursor stay focused on file window, so I want something like :NERDTreeFind + wincmd p

How should I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
map <F5> :NERDTree<cr><c-w>p
```

Comment: `<C-w>p` jumps to the previous window, no matter where it is or how many there are.

Comment: @romainl Oops, my mistake.

Comment: I think that works for me, I will only press F5 from a file window

Comment: @user39569 Yeah, `<C-w>w` normally works for me too. But if you already have 2 or more windows before pressing <f5>, it may not work as expected.